# How can I run two timers separately in background (React Native)

Tags: react-native

I need to set two intervals and manipulate them separately in the application background.
I am using this library - https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer
That gives me a possibility to maintain timers in the background but seems it supports only one at a time. Does anybody had a problem with it and can recommend some solution? 
Thanks for your time and thoughts for advance :)

Answer (score -1):

if you read the Usage example of the library carefully you will find out that it clearly shows two examples. One that can be used to maintain multiple timers and the other (Obsolete) example that does not allow maintaining multiple timers.

Comment: " Crossplatform
To use the same code both on Android and iOS use runBackgroundTimer() and stopBackgroundTimer(). *There can be used only one background timer to keep code consistent.* "

Only one timer, no? In cross-platform solution